# How to compile list of rows from excel and make it as a list array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, list, function

```
def check_duplication(excelfile, col_Date, col_Name):
list_rows[]
```

Uphere is the a bit of the code.
How do I make lists in Python from the excel file? I want to compile every rows that contains the value of Date and Name in the sheet from excel and make it as a list. **The reason I want to make a list because later I want to compare between the rows within the list to check if there is a duplicate within the list of rows.**

Comment: There isn't really anything in that code snippet related to your question

Answer (score 0):

**Dataframe Method**
To compare excel content, you do not need to make a list. But if you want to make a list, one starting point may be making a dataframe, which you can inspect in python. To make a dataframe, use:

```
import pandas as pd
doc_path = r"the_path_of_excel_file"
sheets= pd.read_excel(doc_path, sheet_name= None, engine= "openpyxl", header= None)
```

This code lines read the excel document's all sheets without headers. You may change the parameters.
(For more information: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Assume Sheet1 is the sheet we have our data in:

```
d_frame = sheets[0]
list_rows = [df.iloc[i,:] for i in range(len(d_frame.shape[0]))]
```

I assume you want to use all columns. You may find the list with the code.